# How do I reduce a symmetric matrix to a tridiagonal matrix with the same eigenvalues?

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvalue

I have a symmetric matrix found from the following commands:

```
a=rand(n);
A=triu(a)+triu(a,1)'
```

I was wondering how I reduce this symmetric matrix into a tridiagonal matrix?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to find the *upper Hessenberg* form of your matrix. For a symmetric matrix, this is tridiagonal.

Use the command [hess](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/hess.html) to do this:

```
B=hess(A);
```